# Jquery event handlers return values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any use to return values from `.click()` and `.change()` handlers (like `return true` or `return false`)?

Comment: How do you mean? Show us an example of how you would like to use that result (the return value).

Comment: Just curious since some return true others false and I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`return false;` will stop the event from bubbling up *AND* suppress the default action.

In otherwords, returning false is analogous to these two lines

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

For events that bubble and are cancelable, at least.

Comment: stopPropagation is only for jQuery event handlers (but jquery event handler was the question)

Answer (score 23):

`return false` in such a handler results in `event.stopPropagation()` (only for jQuery event handlers, as Tim Down suggested in the comments) and `event.preventDefault()` being called automatically by jQuery.

`return true` is the same as returning nothing (no action is taken by jQuery).

Comment: In that case, jQuery is taking liberties here: for non-jQuery event handlers, `return false` only prevents the default action and does not stop the event from bubbling.

Comment: @Tim Down: Good to know. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @TimDown To clarify, by "non-jQuery event handlers", do you mean handlers that were attached by other means than the jQuery methods (.on or .live/.bind/.delegate), like addEventListener?

Comment: @JoLiss: `return false` has no effect in event listeners attached using DOM's `addEventListener()`. It works to suppress default behaviour in so-called DOM0 event handlers, such as `document.body.onclick = function() { return false; };`

Comment: By default, a plain `return` (with no specified return value) or just "falling off the edge of the function"-returning will cause the function to return `undefined`. How does jQuery react to this?