# Return value in js events

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery event handlers return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379403/jquery-event-handlers-return-values)

Is it important to return values in js events(like change, click)? If yes where i can use it?

I cant find any information about this.

Answer (score 3):

In case that you want to prevent the default action of the event and stop the propagation of it you can use `return false`, otherwise using `return` statement is not necessary.