# How to perform the same function for enter in textbox as a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following code in an ASP page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <input type="text" id="TextBox1" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
            <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
                if (textbox.length > 0) {
                    alert("Hello world!");
                    window.location.href = "http://westmedgroup.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
                }
                else {
                    alert("Search query empty");
                }
            });
            $('#TextBox1').keyup(function () {
                var $th = $(this);
                $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
            });
            $('#TextBox1').keypress(function (e) {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13) {
                    var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
                    if (textbox.length > 0) {
                        window.location.href = "http://westmedgroup.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
                    }
                    else {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
</asp:Content>
```

When I click the button it does what it is supposed to, if there is a text value then show an alert and then redirect to the search result page otherwise do not re-direct and display a search query empty alert.
I am trying to do the same thing for the textbox but everything I hit enter and there is a text value it just refreshes the page without redirecting.
How do I modify the code so the textbox and the button works like together.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this later, I'm used to pure JS. Here's a quick pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4379459/3227403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing enter in the textbox submits the form, you should e.preventDefault() even when you redirect.

Comment: @SiKni8: To be honest I don't trust my own words anymore. The input is not type="submit" but type="button", so there should be no implicit form action fired. Can you please "return false" (signaling that the event has been handled)? Please tell what the problem and solution was. I'm curious.

Comment: Actually the `e.preventDefault()` did the trick :) I am still testing though.