# Browser Compatibility--- Plain Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to run below code in Chrome Browser Version 43.0.2357.81 m, and OS windows XP.

Below code is work perfectly on Firefox and IE.
is chrome browser compatible with windows Xp or not.

In chrome I am getting TrpeError: translate is not function;

Thanks in Advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function translate(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.which==13){                 
                    alert("You have entered ENTER key");                    
                }
            } 

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></td>

            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" onkeydown="javascript: translate(event)">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"></td>

            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change the function name and it works.

Comment: What is `TrpeError`?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As pointed out by Aaron Digulla, this is not related to Chrome's Content Security Policy as I first thought.  I'll leave this answer up however, as the code below is still a valid approach to handling the event.

```
var passfield = document.getElementById('password');
passfield.onkeydown = function(event) {
     if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.which==13){                 
          alert("You have entered ENTER key");                    
     }
}
```

The following fiddle shows this in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/x0enzmc7/

Comment: The first part of the answer only applies when the server sends a special header to the browser to enable CSP. Specifically, jsfiddle wouldn't work if Chrome would enable CSP by default.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Omit the `javascript:`. This should work:

```
... onkeydown="translate(event)" ...
```

But it's probably less brittle to attach a function to the onload event of the page:

```
function onload() {
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    password.onkeydown = translate;
}
```

Note that `event` might be undefined inside of `translate()`. Use

```
event = event || window.event;
```

to fix that.

Lastly, the function should return `true` or `false`, depending on whether it wants to swallow the event.

As you can see, this is pretty hard to get right. Just add jQuery to your page and use it - it fixes all those pesky issues.

Comment: thanx Aaron, i'm new to javascript, here my question is in javascript function when to use true and false return

Comment: Read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379403/jquery-event-handlers-return-values